# OSGi jar restricted inside a CQ5/ AEM component

Tags: aem, osgi-bundle

Is it possible to install a OSGi jar to Felix by keeping the jar as a part of the cq5 component and install it on build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot restrict an OSGi bundle so that only one CQ component can use it. If an OSGi bundle exports a java package, that will be visible from all java and scripting code.

Comment: That's alright but can we place an osgi jar inside the component's folder, similar to a clientlib folder is placed inside component?

Comment: By default CQ only loads bundles and other installable resources from folders named install or config under /libs or /apps, up to 5 levels (IIRC, configurable) down from /. If your bundle is in a folder that matches these criteria it should get loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can include it in a content package at build time, if you're targeting this with your question. The [multimodule-content-package-archetype](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/core/how_to/how_to_use_the_vlttool/vlt-mavenplugin.html#multimodule-content-package-archetype) provided by Adobe does that as well.

Comment: This approach needs a package to be uploaded and installed using package manager, right? I'm looking to install osgi jar when I build the component as part of my project build, restricting the jar to a component only by placing it inside the component something like a clientlib .

Comment: No, usually you compile the bundle, include it the content package and deploy the content package via Maven.